# swift3 xcode 8.3.3 checking reachability during the app running

Tags: ios, swift3, reachability

swift3 xcode 8.3.3

I made a button to check the reachability, but how to do checking reachability during the app running every second.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func checkAction(_ sender: Any) {
        checkReachability()
    }

    func checkReachability(){
        if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWiFi {
            print("User is connected to the internet via wifi.")
        }else if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWWAN{
            print("User is connected to the internet via WWAN.")
        } else {
            print("There is no internet connection")
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to observe reachability every second because there is a delegate method that will be called when there is any change in internet reachability.

```
func reachabilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
   let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
   switch reachability.currentReachabilityStatus {
   case .notReachable:
   debugPrint(“Network became unreachable”)
   case .reachableViaWiFi:
   debugPrint(“Network reachable through WiFi”)
   case .reachableViaWWAN:
   debugPrint(“Network reachable through Cellular Data”)
 }
}
```

But you will need to start monitoring it by adding method call `startMonitoring()` into `viewDidLoad()` method

```
/// Starts monitoring the network availability status
func startMonitoring() {
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
             selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),
                 name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
               object: reachability)
  do{
    try reachability.startNotifier()
  } catch {
    debugPrint(“Could not start reachability notifier”)
  }
}
```

And finally by adding

```
ReachabilityManager.shared.startMonitoring()
```

So that `ReachabilityManager` will start monitoring for changes.

Comment: if you need to monitor reachability in whole app, you can put this code in AppDelegate

Comment: Am I correct?
In AppDelegate.swift
    func reachabilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
        let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
        switch reachability.currentReachabilityStatus {
        case .notReachable:
            debugPrint("Network became unreachable")
        case .reachableViaWiFi:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through WiFi")
        case .reachableViaWWAN:
            debugPrint("Network reachable through Cellular Data")
        }
    }

Comment: In ViewController.swift, override func viewDidLoad() {func startMonitoring() {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),
                                                   name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
                                                   object: reachability)
            do{
                try reachability.startNotifier()
           } catch {
debugPrint("Could not start reachability notifier")
 }
 }ReachabilityManager.shared.startMonitoring()
 }